# PMD Apex Suppression not working

Tags: apex, pmd

Does anyone have issue with the `@SuppressWarnings('PMD.ApexCRUDViolation')` working sometimes and not working other times?

Usually it doesn't work after `if` statements and will also give us the error "unexpected token '@'" in eclipse.

Comment: For reference, documentation is here: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.5.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html#annotations

Comment: Can you post a complete example source snippet? Annotations cannot be placed everywhere in the source... If you place it after a `if` statement, what exactly is the next statement after annotation? (Annotations usually annotate whatever comes after...)